# Efficient parsing of XML strings in C

Tags: c, xml-parsing

I need to parse `XML` encoded strings returned by an `API`, in `C`, and look out for a particular tag and its value. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? I cannot use non-standard libraries or 3rd party libraries like Boost.

Comment: You can try [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) library.

Comment: `libxml` - 3rd party under `MIT` license. I cannot use it.

Comment: If you can't use any 3rd party library you have to do the parsing yourself. "What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?": this is too broad.

Comment: AFAIK if you cannot use 3rd party library, then the only way is use string operations to get the tag value from the xml input.

Comment: Parsing will be done on a stream of bytes. I suppose I can park the returned stream in a file, using an external piece of code, but then if I am able to do that, I might as well parse it then and there. I do not imagine that is feasible with current constraints. I was looking for a way to do this (parse) several times with no memory leaks, which can always be an issue when dealing with C Strings, especially dynamic ones and with XML in the picture..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it during my course.

You should use chained list to parse your document.

The way I did it (and this way pretty effective) is by parsing the char* straight after the opening '<' first, then, you go through everything until you find the closing '>'. Putting every word into an array is a good idea.

Which means, that everything you read before that point is linked with the very first char * in your array.

After on, you only have to parse 2 more things, the attribute, and its value. The attribute ends by a '=', which means that from the previous space character, till this '=' sign, is the attribute, and everything behind the '=' char to the next ' ', is it's value.

```
<model name="Homo sapiens Glycolysis" id="Pathway146">
```

Here, "model" is the tag, "name" is the attribute and "Homo sapiens Glycolysis" is it's value.

Then, when you've successfully parsed those strings, fill your chained list. Every node is a new tag.

This way, when asked to find a specific field, just go through your list (from the beggining) to the end, searching for a specific tag, attribute, or value. 
When found, display the whole node.

Here was my .h, if it can help.

```
typedef struct   s_elem {
  char           *tag;
  char           **attributes;
  char           **values;
  struct s_elem  *next;
  struct s_elem  *prev;
} t_elem;

typedef struct   s_list {
  struct s_elem  *first;
  struct s_elem  *last;
} t_list;
```

This is not the only way to do it. You can store the attribute and its value into a single string but you'll have to print it taking care of the '='.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It certainly helps. I can fit it to my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple one-off value extraction, you can get away with using string functions (`strstr()` etc) and nesting them according to your XML element order. It won't be pretty, but it should work fine.

If you need something more generalised that you'll be using in multiple applications and that needs to handle variable XML input, XPath, etc. you'll be best off writing your own general-purpose XML parser. You could either go the route of writing your own or use [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) and [Flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/).

**Aside:** I'm not sure *why* you cannot use a third party library - the MIT license is very permissive and most legal departments are happy with it being used in commercial software. To be honest, writing your own XML parser will be painful - `libxml` has been there before and done that well (well, as well as an XML parser can work...).

Comment: Unfortunately it may not be a one off extraction. If I have that guarantee, I can use standard string functions and make it work, but I do not think this will be the case. About the license, yes, it is quite open, but there are bureaucratic hurdles, which might take more time to resolve than if I do ti myself.